# DevOps Pipeline : tree command causing Segmentation fault

Tags: azure-devops

I have a devops yaml pipeline that that uses ubuntu-latest image. It contains a step to list files - handy when diagnosing problems.

```
- task: CmdLine@2
            displayName: List files
            inputs:
              script: |
                echo "Pipeline.Workspace:" 
                echo "$(Pipeline.Workspace)"
                echo "Structure of the work Pipeline.Workspace of this pipeline:"
                tree $(Pipeline.Workspace) /f
```

This pipeline used to work fine but since last week, the task causes a segmentation fault error:

> 1779 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) tree /home/vsts/work/1 /f

Comment: Try reinstalling apt. Download the apt package for latest from [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/), then use dpkg to reinstall apt: `sudo dpkg --install /full/path/to/downloaded/package.deb`

Comment: it's a Microsoft hosted build agent so I've no option to install anything?

Comment: have you tried to specify your image with ubuntu-22.04 or ubuntu-20.04 instead of ubuntu-latest?

Comment: hi rob, is it working on ubuntu 20.04?